# How to store output of an array in a file?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a small powershell script which collects metrics from servers remotely.
In general functions are called to gather the CPU / Memory / HDD info.

I pick up the servers from a text file and foreach machine the functions are getting called.

```
foreach ($i in Get-Content "C:\Servers.txt")
{{"=========================="; $i + "`n" + "==========================";
 "Number of CPU Cores" ; CPU-Info ; "Memory in GB" ; Memory-Info
  ; "HDDs in GB" ; HDD-Size }
```

First I tried to outfile everything using `out-file` but of course every new input overwrote my file.
Is there are way to temporary store the output and out-file it in a good way?

What would you recommend? Maybe there is a much smoother way of doing it?

Comment: Are you looking for `Out-File -Append`? Also, how does the `CPU-Info`, `Memory-Info` functions etc. know which server to collect information from when you don't specify any parameters?

Comment: ah you are right, I did put the $i in the function lol. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what purpose will the output file be used? If it's for human consumption then CSV is probably your best bet, with its ease of import into Excel. If it's for accurate representation of objects then XML is a better idea. Each of those types has its own export cmdlet: `Export-Csv` and `Export-Clixml` respectively.

It might be a better approach to add all your output to an array before then using one of those cmdlets to export all the data in one go. I usually do this sort of thing by creating a custom object for each run of the loop:

```
$OutputFile = 'C:\Output.csv'

$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\Servers.txt'

$OutputArray = @()

foreach ($i in $ServerList)
{
$ServerObject = New-Object PSObject

Add-Member -InputObject $ServerObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'CPU_Cores' -Value (CPU-Info $i)
Add-Member -InputObject $ServerObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Memory_GB' -Value (Memory-Info $i)
Add-Member -InputObject $ServerObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'HDD_Size' -Value (HDD-Size $i)

$OutputArray += $ServerObject
}

$OutputArray | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile
```

Comment: Hey Conan, thank you. Funnier wise, I just did finished the script unsing Export-csv.

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem looks like overwriting instead of appending, you can [ask .Net to provide you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) unique a temp file. The method is `io.path.GetTempFileName()` and it creates a new zero-byte file too. Like so,

```
$tempFile = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()
test-path $tempFile
True
$tempFile
C:\Users\myhomedir\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDA2E.tmp
```

There's another a method, `io.path.GetRandomFileName()` that'll provide you a [cryptographically strong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) random file name. Unlike `GetTempFileName()`, all you get is a name. File creation is up to you.